# What does the namespace config option do for LexicalJS `createEditor`?

Tags: lexicaljs

I can't find anything in the docs. This is what I've found https://lexical.dev/docs/api/modules/lexical#createeditorargs.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from a Lexical dev posted in the Lexical Discord channel:

*"One thing is copy+paste compatibility. If the source and destination namespaces don't match, we fallback to HTML for the transfer format. I thought there was something in collab too, but that might be it"*